# unsatisfied forward or external declaration

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors

I am getting an error while compiling `.pas` file.

> "unsatisfied forward or external declaration :TxxxException.CheckSchemeFinMethodDAException."

Does anyone have any idea what this error implies?

Does it mean that 
`CheckSchemeFinMethodDAException` was not called in all the concerned files?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have declared this method but didn't implement it.

Comment: just press Ctrl+Shift+C to add the method to the implementation section

Answer (score 5):

you may have forgotten to put the class name before the function name within the implementation section. for example, the following code will yield your error:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

type
  TMyClass = class
    function my_func(const text: string): string;
  end;

implementation

function my_func(const text: string): string;
begin
  result := text;
end;

end.
```

to fix, just change the function implementation to `TMyClass.my_func(const text: string): string;`.

Answer (score 3):

```
unit Unit1;

interface

type
  TMyClass = class
    procedure DeclaredProcedure;
  end;

implementation

end.
```

This yields the error you describe. The procedure *DeclaredProcedure* is **declared** (signature) but not **defined** (implementation part is empty).

You have to provide an implementation for the procedure.